# Game crashes when loading Admob smart banner

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, smartbanner

I just upgrade my game to Unity 2019.2.0f1 and Admob 3.18.2

Now it crashes when I load smart banner (other adsize works fine).

Here is the log:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.equals(java.lang.Object)'
>   on a null object reference 08-03 14:57:29.307 19834 19834 E
>   AndroidRuntime:   at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzwu.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.1.1:248)
>   08-03 14:57:29.307 19834 19834 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzwu.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.1.1:87)
>   08-03 14:57:29.307 19834 19834 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.1.1:15)
>   08-03 14:57:29.307 19834 19834 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.1.1:18)
>   08-03 14:57:29.307 19834 19834 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.google.unity.ads.Banner$5.run(Banner.java:278) 08-03 14:57:29.307
>   19834 19834 E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 08-03 14:57:29.307
>   19834 19834 E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 08-03 14:57:29.307
>   19834 19834 E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 08-03 14:57:29.307 19834 19834
>   E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 08-03
>   14:57:29.307 19834 19834 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 08-03 14:57:29.307
>   19834 19834 E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>   08-03 14:57:29.307 19834 19834 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Here is the code:

```
m_BannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);

m_BannerView.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
m_BannerView.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
m_BannerView.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
m_BannerView.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
m_BannerView.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
m_BannerView.LoadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a thread on googleads-mobile-unity github about this issue:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/987

One of contributors replied:
I recommend using Unity version 2019.1.11f1 until we determine the cause of
this. We believe it could be a Unity issue, as the Smart banner reference
is null even when proguard is off.

Comment: Another one posted a working fix!

GetAdSizeJavaObject inside Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Platforms/Android/Utils.cs seems to be broken.

The first return must be changed to: return new AndroidJavaObject(AdSizeClassName, adSize.Width, adSize.Height).GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("SMART_BANNER");

Answer (score 1):

The solution of luvjungle and more specifically the comment of Juan Bentel worked like a charm for me
"Another one posted a working fix! GetAdSizeJavaObject inside Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Platforms/Android/Utils.cs seems to be broken. The first return must be changed to: return new AndroidJavaObject(AdSizeClassName, adSize.Width, adSize.Height).GetStatic("SMART_BANNER"); – Juan Bentel Aug 11 at 8:03 "